# Convert and Assign Pandas Series to a dataframe to create CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I've got order data with SKUs inside and would like to find out, how often a SKU has been bought per month over the last 3 years.

```
for row in df_skus.iterrows():
    df_filtered = df_orders.loc[df_orders['item_sku'] == row[1]['sku']]
    # Remove unwanted rows:
    df_filtered = df_filtered[['txn_id', 'date', 'item_sku']].copy()
    # Group by year and date:
    df_result = df_filtered['date'].groupby([df_filtered.date.dt.year, df_filtered.date.dt.month]).agg('count')

    print ( df_result )
    print ( type ( df_result ) )
```

The (shortened) result looks good so far:

> date  date
>   2017  3       1
>   Name: date, dtype: int64
>   
>   date  date
>   2017  2       1
>         3       6
>         4       1
>         6       1
>   Name: date, dtype: int64

Now, I'd like to create a CSV which looks like that:

```
SKU 2017-01 2017-02 2017-03
17  0       0       1
18  0       1       3
```

Is it possible to simply 'convert' my data into the desired structure?

Comment: Your code doesn't actually make it possible to generate output.  Can you provide the data in `df_skus` needed to generate the shortened result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do these kind of calculations all the time and this seems to be the fastest.

```
import pandas as pd
df_orders = df_orders[df_orders["item_sku"].isin(df_skus["sku"])]
monthly_sales = df_orders.groupby(["item_sku", pd.Grouper(key="date",freq="M")]).size()
monthly_sales = monthly_sales.unstack(0) 
monthly_sales.to_csv("my_csv.csv")
```

- first line filters to the SKUs you want
- the second line does a groupby and counts the number of sales per sku per month
- the next line changes the dataframe from a multi index to the format you want
- exports to csv

Comment: Wow! That is amazing and way more convenient than my approach. I've got so much to learn.
line 3 needs to be df_orders (plural) the rest works exactly as you expected and produces a nice outcome. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! In general, you should almost never use for loops in Pandas. I'm curious though, is only one item purchased at a time? Because this code assumes that.

Comment: Hmm .. thanks for the for loop hint - I'm at home in PHP and Pandas seems to be great but introducing new concepts for me.
There is another column with qty - mostly it's 1 but I'll fiddle it in.